# Is there a way to reference XLA file in Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, vba

I'm trying to set a User Defined Formula (Function) to a cell in Apache POI but Excel doesn't recognize it because it exists in an XLA file. Is there a way to reference that XLA file in POI? I'm thinking of porting XLA file (VBA code) to Java but it's a lot of code!
Any pointers? Thank you.